# Notifications functionality in Django web-site

Tags: python, django, events, signals, messaging

One project that I work on, have a requirement, that every email message to any user must be customizable in admin site. 
I think that such feature is not so unique, and there must be approaches developed for that, so can someone share any?

For now I have such scheme for that:
- Django project can contain multiple decoupled applications (and decoupling is highly desirable)
- Any application might need to send emails
- So the signals must be used here
- It means, that every place in code must have unique sender object, unique name, and description of data that will be send with a signal - admin users will need it to customize messages.
- How to organize that? It might a long big setting in settings.py with sender names and descriptions of data. Or it might be something like Django-models - classes that are stored in special file inside app folder and that are discovered automatically when system starts. Second approach is good, but I dont know how to implement it yet.

Does someone know any better solutions?

Comment: You don't _need_ signals here (but they may help if you want to send mails on already existing signals).

Comment: If your main use case is mails, you could take a look at Django post office: https://github.com/ui/django-post_office